I get this error: returned non-zero exit status 1 while running bin/magento-docker ece-deploy in Magento Cloud with Docker
I'm installing Magento Cloud with Docker on Local from an existing Magento Cloud Production environment.
These are the steps I have done:

Clone the repository
Composer Install
dump database into local
downloaded pub/media
created the build -- ./vendor/bin/ece-docker build:compose --mode="developer" --sync-engine="mutagen"
Created .docker/config.php from config.php.dist
bin/magento docker up -- All docker working
synchronized with bash mutagen.sh
Created app/etc/env.php from cloud app/etc/env.php

Here is where I get the error:
> bin/magento-docker ece-deploy                                                   
 
[+] Creating 3/0
 ✔ Container mc-pro-2cap-opensearch-1  Running                                                                                                                                                                                                                         0.0s 
 ✔ Container mc-pro-2cap-redis-1       Running                                                                                                                                                                                                                         0.0s 
 ✔ Container mc-pro-2cap-db-1          Running                                                                                                                                                                                                                         0.0s 
Running "deploy" hook.
Could not open input file: ./vendor/bin/ece-tools
returned non-zero exit status 1

I get stuck there and can't advance, does anyone know how to fix this? What am I missing?

Great! thanks I will check and see how it goes!
